# How to flush interpreters list cache?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I initialized a virtualenv with a python 2.7 interpreter, and then selected it as the interpreter in VSCode.

I then changed the virtualenv interpreter to python 3.7, and the VSCode interpreter list does not reflects the change: it still shows the virtualenv interpreter as being python 2.7.

How can I force the cached interpreter list to be updated or flushed?

This is related to this [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/666).

Comment: How actually have you "changed the virtualenv interpreter to python3.7"? what's  set in the settings.json/workspace (or user)/ "python.pythonPath"?

Comment: I deleted the `env` folder and re-executed the `virtualenv` command, and then deleted the `.vscode` folder too... Sadly the cache seems to be global to VS Code :(

Comment: Well, then select any other interpreter, and select the desired one back.

Comment: Did you restart VS Code?

Comment: same problem here, i deleted the virtualenv folder, selected another interpreter, then switched back, and i also have restarted my VS Code, still, each time i run the py file, the my Mac will reset! please help !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At last I found a way to remove no-longer existing interpreters from the cache :

- close VSCode
- delete the virtualenv
- launch VSCode and try to select the no-longer existing interpreter

I guess the lookup is only done at launch, and not upon interpreter selection...

Comment: I tried all that but still my VS Code won't run any py file, if i run any, my Mac will bounce up and reset. Please help.

Answer (score 8):

Running those 2 commands in the command palette worked for me.

- Python: Clear Workspace Interpreter Setting
- Python: Reset Stored Info for Untrusted Interpreters

[As mentioned in the GitHub issue here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/3033)
Kudos to ericsnowcurrently

Comment: There is no `Python: Reset Stored Info for Untrusted Interpreters` available anymore

Comment: @motobói - Try `Python: Restart Language Server` instead (as of Version 1.64.2)

Comment: I have a "Go: Restart Language Server" but not "Python: Restart Language Server." Which is weird, because I use Python 99.9% of the time.

Answer (score 3):

Python: Clear Cache and Reload Window

Comment: this is the only option that did it for me.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/2640#issuecomment-948798213), as of October 2021 it is possible to refresh the list of interpreters by doing F1, typing "Python: Select interpreter", and clicking on the circular arrow icon in the top-left corner of the menu.

[image: refresh Python interpreters]